# How to extract the points from a contour line (x,y) with the corresponding z(x,y) values?

Tags: python

I have plotted **z(x,y)** contour line and want to extract the coordinates **x**, **y** along the contour with the corresponding **z(x,y)** values.

How can I do that?

Here is a minimal program segment to explain what I am requesting:

```
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.xlim(-0.06,0.06)  
plt.ylim(-0.06,0.06)
f=open("contourkpt3.txt","w+")
cs=plt.contour(rha,za,ener[:,:,3],[0.15],color=band_color[3])

dat3= cs.allsegs[0][0] 
plt.plot(dat3[:,:])
print(dat3[:,:],file=f)
```

Here in this code, 
 I want not only the `rha`, `za` coordinates extracted along the contour also the corresponding `ener[rha,za,3]` values.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help. In general "how do I x", and "why is x not working" questions are not for SO. Questions should provide a clear problem, that can be easily reproduced, so people helping don't have to spend time getting to where you are, instead we can get to fixing things.

Comment: I have added the minimal code segment to explain the problem. Thanks